# How to store data temporarily on my local machine in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, caching

When i fetch data table  from my Server's database  , i want to store that data on my local machine.

Which is the best method to do ?

Comment: well that depends entirely on your needs. Do you want to store it in memory while your program is running or are you looking to save it in a file on disk?

Comment: @Tejas I want to store in memory.

Comment: Look at the `System.IO` namespace, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/29kt2zfk.aspx. A bunch of classes present in there should be good to serve your needs. Here's another tutorial on serialization http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Vstudio/et91as27.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Enterprise Library Caching block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907) is an example of such a tool

Answer (score 0):

From "store" verb assume you mean disk. If so you can use:

1 - SQL Server Compact (.NET 4.0 & 4.5) with max 4 GB file size restriction or

2 - Better (I use this one personally) SQLite; it's free and open source and has a .NET ADO.NET driver. There is a NuGet for it. I used it with a (lovely) micro ORM named Dapper (which has a NuGet too).